# error: Bad content type. Please use multipart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, xmlhttprequest, google-cloud-storage

I'm totally new to file uploads....I'm using [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload) which creates an XHR ***outside*** of angularjs to upload files to google cloud storage.  When I try to upload I keep getting the error below.  How can I resolve this?

```
400 Bad content type. Please use multipart.
```

Here's my controller setup:

```
var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
      url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/bucketsbuckets/o?uploadType=multipart',
      headers : {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ya29.lgHmbYk-5FgxRElKafV4qdyWsdMjBFoO97S75p4vB0G0d6fryD5LASpf3JUY8Av9Yzhp9cQP8IQqhA', 
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      },
      autoUpload:true
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the endpoint you're using is for multipart uploads, but not FORM-based multipart uploads. If you set your Content-Type to "multipart/related" instead of "multipart/form-data", you should be able to proceed.

A multipart upload to that endpoint, "www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/etc?uploadType=multipart", expects a multipart message with exactly two parts, the first part being the metadata of the object, in JSON, and the second part being the data.

More on these requirements are here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload

If, however, you'd like to do an upload in the style of a form submission,  that's also possible, but the rules are different. In this case, you'll submit a POST to "storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET/OBJECT" with a variety of appropriate form parameters: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference-methods#postobject

Now, this all assumes you're trying to do an upload as a multipart request for some reason. That might be necessary if you need to set some specific metadata properties on the object, but if not, you may be making things harder for yourself. A simple PUT to "storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET/OBJECT" will work just fine  (although I'm not familiar with angular-file-upload and don't know whether it supports non-form-style uploads).

Answer (score 3):

For those who are using `fetch` just remove the `content-type` on your header.

I found this issue on [github](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/505) and I quote:

> Setting the Content-Type header manually means it's missing the boundary parameter. Remove that header and allow fetch to generate the full content type. It will look something like this:
>
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryyrV7KO0BoCBuDbTL
>
> Fetch knows which content type header to create based on the FormData object passed in as > the request body content.

^^ this one worked for me.