# GoogleDrive REST API multipart upload. 400: Bad content type. Please use multipart

Tags: post, request, google-drive-api

I'm trying to upload a file to GoogleDrive using the REST API as written here as a multipart upload with POST request: 
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/multipart-upload.

Trying with the Advanced REST client like the example in the documentation. But with Content-Type "multipart/related" I got an Error:

```
400: Bad content type.  Please use multipart.
```

When using only "multipart" as Content-Type I got:

```
Media type 'multipart' is not supported. Valid media types: [*/*]
```

Still tried all subtypes of multipart (e. g. multipart/mixed, ...) but always got error 400.

Similar error is mentioned here: [error: Bad content type. Please use multipart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30917332/error-bad-content-type-please-use-multipart), but not with "multipart/related" as written in the documentation.

Any idea how to fix the issue?

Thank you and best!

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of trial and error I found the issue: I had `boundary` as a single header parameter, but should be added to `Content-Type` like `multipart/related; boundary=boundary53170215682661314146`. Now it works correct!